# Asp.Net MVC 5 How to send ViewBag to Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a _LoginPartial View and want to send data to it by ViewBag, but the Controller that I'am sending data from, doesn't have a View.

```
public PartialViewResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.sth = // some data
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml");
    }
```

This code didn't work for me.

Comment: did you access `@ViewBag.sth` in the `_LoginPartial` view? This should work

Comment: Create a model and pass it on to the partial view. Using `ViewBag` is not the best practice

Comment: How exactly are you using this PartialViewResult?

Comment: What do you suggest instead of PartialViewResult?

Comment: @CanTunç I need to know where and how you're using it to suggest an alternative. Is it being rendered in another view? Is it being rendered in another controller action? Do you get it via AJAX?

Comment: I use it in a Partial View, it only contains a menu to display for logged-in users, and I render it at main Layout

Comment: @CanTunç can you show me the snippet of code in the main layout where you render it?

Comment: <body> <div> <ul>..</ul> @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial") </div> </body>

Comment: @CanTunç see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

It seems you're expecting this `Index` action to be called when you do: `@Html.Partial('_LoginPartial')`. That will never happen. `Partial` just runs the partial view through Razor *with the current view's context* and spits out the generated HTML.

If you need additional information for your partial, you can specify a custom `ViewDataDictionary`:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", new ViewDataDictionary { Foo = "Bar" });
```

Which you can then access inside the partial via:

```
ViewData["Foo"]
```

You can also use child actions, which is generally preferable if working with a partial view that doesn't need the context of the main view. `_LoginPartial` seems like a good candidate, although I'm not sure how exactly you're using it. Ironically, though, the `_LoginPartial` view that comes with a default MVC project with individual auth uses child actions.

Basically, the code you have would already work, you would just need to change how you reference it by using `Html.Action` instead of `Html.Partial`:

```
@Html.Action("Index")
```

Notice that you're calling the *action* here and now the view.

Comment: this is what worked for me `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", new ViewDataDictionary {{"Foo ", "Bar"}, {"Foo2", "Bar2"}})`

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass data directly to the partial view.

```
public PartialViewResult Index()
{
    var data = // some data
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", data);
}
```

Pass multiple pieces of data

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public PartialViewResult Index()
{
    var data = new MyModel(){ Prop1 = 5, Prop2 = 10 };
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml", data);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to send more then one data?

Comment: The answer is not correct in the context of the question. It is true that you can pass data using the model. But the question is to pass data in the Viewbag

Comment: @kumarharsh using `ViewBag` is inherently bad practice, especially for passing "more than one data". No need to downvote.

Comment: @trailmax I agree with what you are suggesting, but the question is for setting data in the Viewbag and not passing data in the model. Down was because it is not a solution for this question. If it was a question how to pass data in the View, agree with the solution mentioned above

Comment: @kumarharsh Again, please read up on the [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I tried this way but my _LoginPartialView is getting the same model with HomeController's index's model, is there a way to change it?

Comment: Did you specify in your Partial View what model it's using?

Comment: It gives this error when I specify it: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type ..

Answer (score 0):

I passed viewBag data to my partial view like below, and I converted that viewBag data object to JSON in my partial view by using @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Part));

my code sample is given below.

```
 public async  Task<ActionResult> GetJobCreationPartialView(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new ApiClient<ServiceRepairInspectionViewModel>("ServiceRepairInspection/GetById");
                var resultdata = await client.Find(id);

                var client2 = new ApiClient<PartViewModel>("Part/GetActive");  
                var partData = await client2.FindAll(); 

                var list = partData as List<PartViewModel> ?? partData.ToList();
                ViewBag.Part = list.Select(x => new SelectListItem() {Text = x.PartName, Value = x.Id.ToString()});
                return PartialView("_CreateJobCardView" ,resultdata);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

Here i have passed both  model and viewBag .

Answer (score -1):

First off, the code in your question does not run. When you do `@Html.Partial("_SomeView")` the Index() method you have there does not run. All `@Html.Partial("_SomeView")` does is render `_SomeView.cshtml` in your current view using the current view's ViewContext.

In order to get this to work you need a bit of functionality that's common to all the controllers in your project. You have two options: extension method for `ControllerBase` or a `BaseController` that all the controllers in your project inherit from.

**Extension method:**

Helper:

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public static string GetCommonStuff(this ControllerBase ctrl)
    {
        // do stuff you need here
    }
}
```

View:

```
@ViewContext.Controller.GetCommonStuff()
```

**BaseController**

Controller:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public string GetCommonStuff()
    {
        // do stuff you need here
    }
}
```

Other controllers:

```
public class SomeController : BaseController
...
...
```

View:

```
@((ViewContext.Controller as BaseController).GetCommonStuff())
```

Comment: -1 Calling controller methods directly from views is definitely not the right way to use any MVC framework. Please don't recommend this to people

Comment: @ZolaKt That's fair. Could you tell me how you would solve this user's problem?

Comment: There are probably a million workarounds, but I agree with what most people said in comments on other answers. Using the ViewBag is generally a bad idea. Make a ViewModel and pass it around as Model, don't use ViewBag and/or ViewData at all. They are Microsoft made up concepts that shouldn't exist in any clean MVC framework, even less in a strongly typed framework like .NET. If you don't want to repeat the code, you can always make a base controller and a base ViewModel, and populate the "common" stuff in the base controller

Comment: If nothing else using ViewBag/ViewData destroys the biggest advantage of using a strongly typed language like C#, which is refactoring. Meaning, you can simply find all references of some property, rename it or whatever... The only way to "find references" with ViewBags is by property name comparison, which obviously leads  to problems. Even Resharper often gets lost with them. If you want "dynamics everywhere" there is no point in using .NET at all, you are just "tilting at windmills". There are a lot of great dynamic languages available these days.