# Pass ViewBag from Controller to Partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-partialview, viewbag

My controller action is

```
public ActionResult Generate(int? id, int? kol)
{
    string name = db.Sifres.Where(c => c.id == id).Select(c => c.name).FirstOrDefault();

    ViewBag.Sif = name;

    return PartialView("_GenerateNumbers");
}
```

Through debugger and breakpoints I can see that variable `name` and `ViewBag.Sif` have values. When the controller returns partial view the values of variable `name` and `ViewBag.Sif` are **null**! Why? Why those loose their values?

Comment: You may take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310805/asp-net-mvc-5-how-to-send-viewbag-to-partial-view

Answer (score 0):

Usually for a Partial View, I send it a model containing all the data I want, but if you really only need to send this one string, just send it explicitly:

```
return PartialView("_GenerateNumbers", name);
```